# System.IO.StreamWriter does not contain a method named 'writeline'

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell 5.1 and I've got a problem with StreamWriter.
I'm using this code :

```
$ExportFile = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("c:\temp\test.txt")
$ExportFile.WriteLine("Date,User,MyTest")
$ExportFile.Close()
```

When I run the script with PowerShell ISE, it works.
But, When I run the script in PowerShell window, it does not
Here what I have :

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'WriteLine'.
At D:\Scripts\[AD MCO] Audit UsrCptr For Deletion\Audit_UsrCptr_For_Deletionv2.ps1:55 char:7
+       $ExportFile.WriteLine("Date,User, ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
PS D:\Scripts\[AD MCO] Audit UsrCptr For Deletion> host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.14393.3471
InstanceId       : 6904efae-80c0-4e51-a115-e2e580a644a7
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : fr-FR
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

Comment: Anywhere in your script prior to the point where it fails, did you perhaps declare `$ExportFile` a `[string]`? Like `[string]$ExportFile = "somevalue"`. That would explain the behavior

Comment: The error message implies that `$ExportFile` contains a `[string]` instance, not a `[System.IO.StreamWriter]` instance, so you need to investigate that (see Mathias' comment). Also note that in the ISE repeated runs of a script are performed with dot-sourcing in the same scope, so previous runs can affect subsequent ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "error". There was a special caracter in the script that modify the execution. I wrote again the script with notepad and all is working now. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Any advice as to what the "special character" was?